# GORM/groovy automatic casting of String into various objects

Tags: grails, groovy, casting, grails-orm

Another newbie issue. I have a  situation where I have to assign a value to domain class property in groovy.

The code is

> cf."$it.key" = it.value

the property type for cf."$it.key" can be Integer, Long  or String - but it.value is always a  String. I have seen that when cf."$it.key" is Integer or Long, groovy converts it.value to ascii value( for example if it.value is "6", cf."$it.key" becomes 54, when it is "7", it becomes 55 and so on). As of now, I have resolved the issue by introducing check methods as shown below. But was wondering if there is a better solution to the problem.

> ```
>               if (it.value.isInteger()){
>                   cf."$it.key" = new Integer(it.value)
>               }
>               else if (it.value.isLong()){
>                   cf."$it.key" = new Long(it.value)
>               }
> ```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're iterating through a map,you should be able to [use bindData](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Controllers/bindData.html), i.e.

```
bindData( cf, map )
```

Make sure you read that section of the docs though, as there are security implications